# Power BI text to date format

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table in Power BI with a column Calendar Year/Month as text. The values are yyyymm (ex. 202108), I am trying to convert it into Date

[image]

but when I change the format to date, I get an error.

[image]

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the many ways, you can do

```
ToDate = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Calendar Year/Month", each Date.FromText(_, [Format="yyyyMM"]), type date}}),
```